# How to split a dataset with multiple variables into train and test while both having the same composition using python?

Tags: python

I have a list of brain metastasis MRIs that I want to use for training and testing purposes.
These images are all similar but the original tumor sites differs. See the following example:

From Lungs:

- "Image01.1"
- "Image01.2"
- "Image01.3"
- "Image01.4"

From Breasts:

- "Image02.1"
- "Image02.2"
- "Image02.3"
- "Image02.4"
- "Image02.5"

From Skin:

- "Image03.1"
- "Image03.2"

From Lung Tissue:

- "Image04.1"
- "Image04.2"
- "Image04.3"

From Bone Marrow:

- "Image05.1"
- "Image05.2"

I want the testing and validation set to contain the same amount of images without losing a similar composition (both lists containing the same amount of each subtype).

For this purpose can I create lists for each subtype and then randomly split those 50/50. Followed by adding all these lists together?

Comment: One thing to consider would be image sets with an odd number of elements: if you just do selection without replacement for 50% of the elements, you might waste the odd observation out. Other than that, though, it sounds like you've answered your own question... Unless you're asking for the actual code to accomplish this...?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am indeed looking for some code that can read of the excell file and match the correct primary tumor site to the correct image to then put that in a list. I have tried the following:                                                       lung_patients = []
with open(r"B:/.../excell.csv", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect="excel",delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        if row[33] == 'Lung': 
            lung_patients.append(row[1])

Comment: However this does not seem to do what I want, also the file name in excell is a shortened version of the actuall safe file and not equal anymore after the 15th character. How would I tackle this?

Comment: You should put what you already tried in the actual question part instead of in the comments (so that it's more visible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get specific rows from a pandas DataFrame that meet certain criteria, you can filter. In your case, something like:

```
reader_lung = reader[reader["Image_Title"] == "Lung"]
```

`"Image_Title"` you need to change to the name of the column you're looking for your keyword (e.g., Lung) in. This needs to be an exact match.

For something that doesn't require an exact match, you could also do the following:

```
reader_lung = reader[reader["Image_Title"].str.contains("Lung")]
```

Comment: Thanks! Not necessarily what I was looking for but I can restructure and use this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a list of lists (one for each type) and then take the first N and put them into training and the last N and put them in test?

Something like this pseudocode:

```py
with open(r"B:/.../excell.csv", newline='') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect="excel",delimiter=';')
    test = []
    training = []

    type_map = {}
    for row in reader: 
        if row[33] in type_map:
            # If the type has already been viewed, append to the existing list of those images
            type_map[row[33]].append(row)
        else:
            # If this type is seen for the first time, create a new array with that row in it
            type_map[row[33]] = [row]

    # Now you should have a map like : {"Lung": ["image1", "image2" ...], "Heart": ["imageA"....]}

    for image_type in type_map:
        type_images = type_map[image_type]
        half_way_index = len(type_images)/2 # For odd elements i.e 13 elems this will give you 6 (integer division)

        test += type_images[0:half_way_index] # First half of the type_images are test
        training += type_images[half_way_index:(half_way_index*2)] # Second half are training
```

Comment: This code does not randomise but I can add that in once I have the lists complete. Thanks!